# java.lang.NullPointerException: error - app is not opening

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am having trouble solving this error as I am new to Android.
I got this null pointer exception error and my app is not opening.

Error:

> 02/11 22:34:19: Launching app Cold swapped changes. $ adb shell am
>   start -n
>   "com.ahsanburney.quicknotes/com.ahsanburney.quicknotes.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Connected to process 3071 on device Nexus_4_API_21 [emulator-5554]
>   I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is
>   com.ahsanburney.quicknotes, real application class is null. W/art:
>   Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile
>   /data/data/com.ahsanburney.quicknotes/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex
>   ( canonical path
>   /data/data/com.ahsanburney.quicknotes/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex)
>   with checksum 0x428a55bf in OatFile
>   /data/data/com.ahsanburney.quicknotes/cache/slice-slice_1-classes.dex
>   W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable D/MainActivity: loadFile: Loading
>   JSON File D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.ahsanburney.quicknotes, PID: 3071
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.ahsanburney.quicknotes/com.ahsanburney.quicknotes.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.ahsanburney.quicknotes.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:61)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6023)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2940)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>   Application terminated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  private TextView dateTime;
  private EditText notes;
  private Data_Saved data_saved;
  private String nChange;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d, h:mm a");
      String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
      dateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastupdated);
      dateTime.setText(date);
      notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_notes);
      notes.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onStart();
      data_saved = loadFile();  // Load the JSON containing the product data - if it exists
      if (data_saved != null) { // null means no file was loaded

          if(data_saved.getdateTime().equals(""))
          {
              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d, h:mm a");
              String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
              dateTime.setText(date);

          }
          else{
              dateTime.setText(data_saved.getdateTime());}
          if(data_saved.getnotes().equals(""))
          {
              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d, h:mm a");
              String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
              dateTime.setText(date);

          }
          notes.setText(data_saved.getnotes());
          nChange = data_saved.getnotes();
      }
  }

  private Data_Saved loadFile() {

      Log.d(TAG, "loadFile: Loading JSON File");
      data_saved = new Data_Saved();
      try {
          InputStream is = getApplicationContext().openFileInput("data_saved.json");
          JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

          reader.beginObject();
          while (reader.hasNext()) {
              String name = reader.nextName();
              if (name.equals("dateTime")) {
                  data_saved.setdateTime(reader.nextString());
              } else if (name.equals("notes")) {
                  data_saved.setnotes(reader.nextString());
              } else {
                  reader.skipValue();
              }
          }
          reader.endObject();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "No file is Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return data_saved;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      data_saved.setdateTime(dateTime.getText().toString());
      data_saved.setnotes(notes.getText().toString());

      saveNotes();
  }

  private void saveNotes() {


      if (nChange.equals(data_saved.getnotes())) {
          return;

      } else {



          Log.d(TAG, "saveNotes: Saving JSON File");
          try {

              FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("data_saved.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

              JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
              writer.setIndent("  ");
              writer.beginObject();
              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d, h:mm a");
              String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
              writer.name("dateTime").value(date);
              writer.name("notes").value(data_saved.getnotes());
              writer.endObject();
              writer.close();






          /// You do not need to do the below - it's just
              /// a way to see the JSON that is created.
              ///
              StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
              writer = new JsonWriter(sw);
              writer.setIndent("  ");
              writer.beginObject();
              //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d, h:mm a");
              //String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
              //dateTime.setText(date);
              //writer.name(date);
              //xmlSerializer.text(date);
              writer.name("dateTime").value(data_saved.getdateTime());

              writer.name("notes").value(data_saved.getnotes());
              writer.endObject();
              writer.close();
              Log.d(TAG, "saveNotes: JSON:\n" + sw.toString());
              ///
              ///

              Toast.makeText(this, "Notes Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.getStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: `at com.ahsanburney.quicknotes.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:61)` This says the error occurs on line 61 in MainActivity.java. Start there.

Comment: p.s. You should install Android Studio since Eclipse is no longer supported by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Check main activity line 61. The null pointer exception is being thrown because `String.equals()` function is made to operate on a null object.

Make sure the objects returned from `data_saved.getdateTime()` and `data_saved.getnotes()` is not null before you apply the `String.equals()` function.